# I get "Incorrect argument" error when i try to run a simple test on couchbase nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

```
var couchbase = require("couchbase");



var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('127.0.0.1:8091');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('beer-sample', function(err) {
    if (err) {

        throw err;
    }



    bucket.get('aass_brewery-juleol', function(err, result) {
        if (err) {

            throw err;
        }

        var doc = result.value;

        console.log(doc.name + ', ABV: ' + doc.abv);

        doc.comment = "Random beer from Norway";

        bucket.replace('aass_brewery-juleol', doc, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {

                throw err;
            }

            console.log(result);


            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my file. It's the example from here : http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/hello-couchbase.html

So when i try to run the server with "nodejs test1.js"  i get "Incorrect argument" error.

At bucket.js, module.js and in cluster.js into node_modules/couchbase/lib/

I have installed couchbase and i have full nodejs installed. I'm new in this and i cant understand where is my mistake. Maybe something with the versions of the couchbase or the node version i dunno.

Here is my full error which i get into the terminal:

```
Error: Incorrect argument
at New Bucket (home/anton/node_modules/couchbase/lib/bucket.js:213:16)
at Object<anonymus> (home/anton/PhpstormProjects/couchbase/test1.js:6:22)
at Cluster.openBucket (home/anton/node_modules/couchbase/lib/cluster.js:37:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

Comment: Where (which line) do you get the error?

Comment: i edited my question about the full error

Comment: According to the docs: https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode#introduction it looks like `new couchbase.Cluster('127.0.0.1:8091');` should be `new couchbase.Cluster();`

Answer (score 0):

The "Canonical" format for connecting to a cluster is `couchbase://host` where *host* in your case is `localhost`.

Depending on the version you're using, newer enhancements may have been added to allow for the common `host:8091` antipattern, but would still be incorrect.

Chances are your code can still work if you upgrade to a newer version - but you should still use the `couchbase://` variant (without the port).